# fastest and concurrent NOSQL database

Tags: java, database, nosql

Which NOSQL DB can I use to have concurrent writes and read for around 2000 to 5000 users? I used MongoDB but that is not working as concurrency is not possible in mongoDB. And yes I want to use that NOSQL DB in my JAVA code.

Comment: Do you need it to be concurrent or fast? If you need it to be fast, how fast do you need it to be? e.g. read/writes per second. If you just want to use all your cores, how many cores do you have? The number of users shouldn't matter as a single user should be able to use all the resources of the machines.

Comment: That's not a matter for me.. I have a java program in which it connects around 2000 users to a server and send their requests to server and receive responses from the server. And this is done using threding in java. So, I want to store all requests and responses for each user simultaneously in the database.

Comment: I think you need to get a clearer idea of what your requirements are. If you you have 2000 users placing one request every 20 seconds and each request takes 1 ms, you will be doing an average of 0.1 request at any one time. i.e. less than 1. Unless you know you need concurrency you should assume you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we use [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) quite successful, it's write optimated db solution, which has multiple client options http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions, e.g.  [the Java Hector Client](http://hector-client.github.com/hector/build/html/index.html).
Cassandra is made for horizontal scaling, so if the performance is unsufficiant we just add another node (server) and the performance goes up.

We do thousands of concurrent writes in one seconds and we haven't really started to scale horizontal.

Comment: Can u give me some links where I can get examples of using Hector in java? Some examples is what I want. To connect to database server and how to use it...

Comment: Try https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-tutorial. A simple connection is created like in https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorial/TutorialBase.java

Answer (score 0):

You can try Apache cassandra, it supports high volume of concurrent writes with clustering.

Comment: is it possible to use cassandra with java? As I was searching on that but I was not getting how to configure in java. So, can u help?